# AngularJs Geolocation

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to build an app that gets the users current location, then queries an api services that then returns data based upon the users position.

The two problems I am facing, is that when the app is first initialized it asked the user to grant permission to use locationwatch this takes around 10 – 30 seconds the find there location but I have a controller function that needs to run after this is complete in order to fire off the http get request for the data.

When I run the problem now I get locationwatch.postion is undefined because the above has not yet taken place.

Can anyone give me any sample code or guidance on how to solve this problem?

Comment: Show your code please

Comment: Try google. When I search for ["_angular geolocation_"](https://www.google.com/search?q=angular+geolocation+example&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&hl=en&client=safari) (which is very easy to do), I see lots of results, including links to working examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you should be using the [$q Service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24q) to make a promise.

A great tutorial on Promises is this one: https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-promises

EDITED to add example:

```
angular.module('yourApp',[])
.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/',{
                controller:'yourCtrl',
                resolve:{
                    geoLocation:['$q',function($q){
                        var defer = $q.defer();
                        if (navigator.geolocation) {
                            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
                                defer.resolve(position);
                            }, function(error) {
                                defer.reject();
                            },{timeout:5000});
                        }else{
                            defer.reject();
                        }
                        return defer.promise;
                    }]
                }
            })
```

Then you can access the 'position' object by injecting it on your controller:

```
.controller('yourCtrl',['geoLocation',function(geoLocation){
   //Code
}])
```

Comment: Can you provide me with any examples using geolocation?

Comment: @Danny620 - Your issue sounds like it pertains to callbacks and/or Angular promises, not geolocation.

Comment: What about geowatchlocation?

Comment: As @jahroy said, its about how you should use Angular promises to handle asynchronous events. Nonetheless, I added a simple example of how it should be implemented, please watch the video so that you can understand how Promises work, since they are very useful